# inner join table (inverse) using larvel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im new to this laravel eloquent so bare with me. Im doing a search function for **Payment**. everything is doing fine, until i need to inner join a table **Contract** for me to output **$payment->contract->account_no** in a search result.

i just need to convert this SQL to eloquent (*i only included **account_no** since its the column that i need get in **Contract***)

```
SELECT 
tbt_contracts.account_no , tbt_payments.payment_type, tbt_payments.payment_mode, tbt_payments.payment_date, tbt_payments.payment_amount, tbt_payments.payment_due_date,
tbt_payments.payee_name
FROM tbt_payments
INNER JOIN tbt_contracts ON tbt_payments.contract_id = tbt_contracts.id
WHERE tbt_contracts.account_no LIKE '%test%'
```

Payment Model

```
    public function contract()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contract::class);
    }
```

Contract Model

```
    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }
```

Payment Controller (when i click the search button)

```
$filters = [];
                //account_no (ERROR)
                !is_null($request->account_no) ? array_push($filters, ['account_no', 'like','%'.$request->account_no.'%']) : null;  
                
                //payment_type
                !is_null($request->payment_type) ? array_push($filters, ['payment_type', 'like','%'.$request->payment_type.'%']) : null; 

                //payment_mode
                !is_null($request->payment_mode) ? array_push($filters, ['payment_mode', 'like','%'.$request->payment_mode.'%']) : null;     
                
                //payee_name
                !is_null($request->payee_name) ? array_push($filters, ['payee_name', 'like','%'.$request->payee_name.'%']) : null; 

                return view('transaction.payment.paymentlist', [
                    'payments' => Payment::where($filters)->orderBy('id')->paginate(10),
                    'payment_modes' => LogicCONF::getDropDownJson('payment_mode.json'),
                    'payment_types' => LogicCONF::getDropDownJson('payment_type.json'),
                ]);
```

working code (works without table join, errors with table join)

```
                return view('transaction.payment.paymentlist', [
                    'payments' => Payment::where($filters)->orderBy('id')->paginate(10),
                ]);
```

DB Facade:

I tried DB Facade. my problem with it is i cannot use or call **Public Function** inside my payment model. (i haven't even tried joining the tables)

```
$payments = DB::table("tbt_payments")->orderBy('id')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: $payments = Payment::with("contract")
                                ->where($filters)
                                ->groupBy("id")
                                ->orderBy('id')
                                ->paginate(10);

tried this but still cannot use "contract_id" in where clause

Answer (score 0):

done.
for some reason innerjoin dont work,
also thanks to this [SQLtoEloquent](https://jjlabajo.github.io/SQLtoEloquent/)

```
$payments = Payment::with("contract")
                ->leftJoin("tbt_contracts", function($join){
                    $join->on("tbt_payments.contract_id","tbt_contracts.id");
                })
                ->where($filters)
                ->select('tbt_payments.*')
                // ->groupBy("tbt_payments.id")
                ->orderBy('tbt_payments.id')
                ->paginate(10);
```